# Wordpress Search Results show results which is broken link

Tags: php, wordpress

The site search is showing the result correctly for some reason the link for the result is broken.

**Example**

```
<a href="http://example.com/health-safety/">Health Safety</a>
```

This is what I get from the search results. In fact the link should have been going to the following page.

```
http://example.com/careers/working-for-us/
```

From the admin, I have entered this information's under posts with categories.

**Here's the PHP Code (I don't think anything is wrong with PHP Code)**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <ul class="searchul table-striped">
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <li>
                            <h4 ><a href="<?php permalink_link();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            <?php the_excerpt();?>  
                        </li>                   
                <?php endwhile; ?>      
                </ul>
                <div class="search-results-paginglinks"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <div class="search_result_error" style="margin-top: 25px;"><?php _e('Sorry, Your search did not match any criteria.' ); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

**More information**
I have tried adding this code to functions.php. What does this does is only queries and searches pages and not posts. I need pages and posts

```
/* Search */    
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'pages');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's `the_permalink()`, not `permalink_link()`

Secondly the post type is called **page** not pages for your pre_get_posts function.